# How to check SQL Server is availability using C# and ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I have client server architecture. I have server and 4 client machines, each client has SQL Server connected with LAN.

I need to check the 4 client database was connected or not.

In my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.90,1433;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=sql2008;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DBConnection1" 
         connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.91,1433;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=sql2008;Connection Timeout=5" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DBConnection2" 
         connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.92,1433;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=sql2008;Connection Timeout=5" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DBConnection3" 
         connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.93,1433;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=sql2008;Connection Timeout=5" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DBConnection4" 
         connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.94,1433;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=sql2008;Connection Timeout=5" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my ASP.NET code, I am using an ajax method inside the for loop

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function CheckDB() {

         for (var i = 1; i <= 4); i++) {
             var DBConnection = "DBConnection" + i;
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'StockIntegration.aspx/CheckDB',
                 data: "{DBConnection:" + JSON.stringify(DBConnection) + "}",
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (data) {

                     if (data.d == null || data.d == undefined) {

                     } else {

                         if (data.d == "1") {
                             $('[id$=Label1]').append("CONNECTED SYSTEM: " + DBConnection + "<br/>");
                         } else {
                             $('[id$=Label2]').append("DISCONNECTED SYSTEM: " + DBConnection + "<br/>");
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 error: function ()
                 { alert('there is some error'); }
             });
         }
     }
 </script>
```

In my web service

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static String CheckDB(String DBConnection)
{
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DBConnection].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select 1", con);
            con.Open();
            var rowCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();
            return rowCount.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Fasle";
        }
}
```

The loop will close if any of SQL Server instances is disconnected. How to achieve this? I need to show the list of connected and disconnected SQL Server instances.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your frontend client javascript code. But only success part of it:

```
success: function (data) {
                 if (data == null || !data) {
                      $('[id$=Label2]').append("DISCONNECTED SYSTEM: " + DBConnection + "<br/>");
                 } else {                   
                      $('[id$=Label1]').append("CONNECTED SYSTEM: " + DBConnection + "<br/>");
                 }
             },
```

this is your c# backend code.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool CheckDB(String DBConnection)
{
    try
    {
        using(var con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DBConnection].ConnectionString);
        {
            con.Open();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
 }
```